# How to get matching values between two DataFrames without iterating

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas `DataFrame` called `df1`, which looks like:

```
value     analysis_date                   hour   error
7         2000-01-01 00:00:00    9      None
8         2000-01-01 00:00:00    10     None
9         2000-01-01 00:00:00    11     None
```

And a second `DataFrame`, `df2`:

```
value     analysis_date          hour   error
4         2000-01-01 09:00:00    1      None
5         2019-01-01 00:00:00    2      None
6         2000-01-01 08:00:00    3      None
```

I want to

- compare 'corresponding' rows, which means rows in which `analysis_date` + `hour` are equivalent between `df1` and `df2`; meaning that `df1` rows 2 and 3 correspond with `df2` rows 3 and 1 respectively
- Then, I want to set the `error` column in `df1` to be `df1['value'][row] - df2['value'][row]` for that corresponding row. So in this case, `df1` should end up looking like this:

```
value     analysis_date                   hour   error
7         2000-01-01 00:00:00    9      None
8         2000-01-01 00:00:00    10     4
9         2000-01-01 00:00:00    11     3
```

Is there a way I can do this beyond looping through every single row and individually comparing them using `iterrows()`?

Answer (score 0):

you could go about it like :

```py
df1['analysis_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['analysis_date'])
df2['analysis_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['analysis_date'])
df2['total_date'] = df2.analysis_date + df2.hour.astype('timedelta64[h]')
df1['total_date'] = df1.analysis_date + df1.hour.astype('timedelta64[h]')
mr_df = df1.merge(df2.loc[:,['value', 'total_date']], on = 'total_date', how = 'left')
df1['error'] = mr_df['value_x'] - mr_df['value_y']
df1 
#   value       date  hour  error          total_date
# 0      7 2000-01-01     9    NaN  2000-01-01 09:00:00
# 1      8 2000-01-01    10    4.0  2000-01-01 10:00:00
# 2      9 2000-01-01    11    3.0  2000-01-01 11:00:00
```

Comment: I updated all my date column names to be `analysis_date` btw- that was a typo

Comment: `mr_df['value_x'] - mr_df['value_y']` gives me a series with the right values, but it doesn't apply to the dataframe properly. It always sets all of them to whatever the first number in the series is

Comment: yeah that was the first solution that I gave and it was wrong , I mentioned that I edited it, it's because I forgot the `how = left` parameter .

Comment: * `how = 'left'`